# Only in jsp javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

Hello i have a web app spring+hibernate

I jsp i tried to read a state of a product

```
<p>${product.state }</p>
```

In my POJO class

```
public class Product
{
   ...
   public String getState(){
       if(this.type == 6)
         return "A";
       if(propertyB.getRole()== 15)
         return "B"
   }
}
```

when a product looking to access a property that is another entity like `propertyB` Throws

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session

Because i change my query with `LEFT JOIN FETCH`

```
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.propertyB b
```

When i get a list of my prodcuts in a Test of Junit **works**

When i get a list of my products in my jsp file Throws

> javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could
>   not initialize proxy - no Session

When i get a list of my products in the Controller like

```
for(Product p: listOfProducts){
    log.put(p.getState());
}
```

**Works fine!!**

**But only in jsp not work**  why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html).  It's a filter that will attach a database session to the thread that is rendering the jsp.

You set it up in your web.xml just as you would any other J2EE filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Hibernate.initialize(yourObject)` before passing it on to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to Eager fetch if you want to automatically resolve the child property. If not, you will need to query the child passing the parent's id. The latter is probably the preferred way of doing (at least for me), because you may not always need to eagerly fetch the children. This will however require a new hibernate session.

I think with your unit test, you initialize session before every test.

Comment: Yes i initialze, but in controller just before the jsp works very wll

Comment: You're only getting an error when you access propertyB? Is that property a child table/class or a column within the class? If it is latter then it is a matter of session not being initialized. Can you also paste what your configuration looks like? The exception tells me it is a child class/property.